# Alpha textures show only when selected

Tags: texturing, transparency

I'm making a radar display animation (those spinning once) for a movie project. What I do is:

1. Set up a material in cycles to see how it fits together (using b&w images)
2. Create alpha textures to make animations using object planes
3. Replace alpha textures with b&w once for compositing

The alpha textures show only when selected and what's worse it has to be done one by one (twelve planes with textures). I followed this video for the "draw order" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mSGOTaoCgM, but it never works. I need the textures to show when the camera is selected.
Expected result -
[image]
What I get -
[image]
blend_file - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37452
texture 1 - http://www.pasteall.org/pic/91624
texture 2 - http://www.pasteall.org/pic/91625
texture 3 - http://www.pasteall.org/pic/91626
I'm not expecting others to fix it, I want to know what's the problem and how can I fix it

Comment: Instead of posting three files you can **pack** the images into the file so they all get saved together.

Comment: If you switch to rendered view you can see the transparency correctly

Comment: This seems to be the function of the viewport. The rendered result is as expected for myself. If  you're issue is with the viewport, unfortunately the only way around this is selecting active elements or using rendered view. If you're issue is with the rendered result I suggest updating blender.

Comment: @Terus The reason for alpha textures is for fast preview of animations so I guess in the video it has to do with the version of the program. Thanks ;)

Comment: @cegaton I did, but transparency effects weren't packed so I had to do them separately. As for the issue above, I'll see if it's a bug. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the files needed to evaluate the problem has expired on pasteall